# Missing data in coulmns in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Hi I enter the 4 record in database, everything is fine, the records I entered through the form are added successfully to the database but when I browse the table there are 4 record available but contents of record is missing, please help. Thanks.

**Code**

```
  <body> 
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "test";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO names (firstname, secondname) VALUES ('', '')";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?> 
    <?php echo $_POST["firstname"]; ?><br /> 
    <?php echo $_POST["secondname"]; ?> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

**Sceenshot**

[image]

Comment: can you please describe more?

Comment: You need to show us some code for us to be able to help you

Comment: post your code (tried one)

Comment: <body>
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO names (firstname, secondname)
VALUES ('', '')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?> 
<?php
echo $_POST["firstname"];?><br />
<?php echo $_POST["secondname"];?>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing any value to column.

Change

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO names (firstname, secondname) VALUES ('', '')";
```

To

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO names (firstname, secondname) VALUES ('".$_POST['firstname']."', '".$_POST['secondname']."')";
```

But, Use [Prepared Statements](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

> A **prepared statement** is a feature used to execute the same (or
>   similar) SQL statements repeatedly with high efficiency. Prepared
>   statements are very useful against SQL injections, because parameter
>   values, which are transmitted later using a different protocol, need
>   not be correctly escaped. If the original statement template is not
>   derived from external input, SQL injection cannot occur.

**Updated Code**

```
<body> 
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "test";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO names (firstname, secondname) VALUES  (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST["firstname"], $_POST["secondname"]);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?> 
    <?php echo $_POST["firstname"]; ?><br /> 
    <?php echo $_POST["secondname"]; ?> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nana Partykar :-)

Comment: *Happy To Help.* @TahirKhan Bhai. But, Please go through my answer once again. It will help you to avoid SQL Injection.